# Net-SNMP showing wrong version in Syslog?

Tags: linux, net-snmp

I built Net-SNMP 5.7.2 from source and installed it. When I run `snmpget --version` and `snmpd --version` it displays the correct version.

However only because of the fact that I am experiencing some SNMP related errors at the moment, I checked my `/var/log/syslog` for any entries. Surprisingly it has the following:

> Apr 11 23:07:00 ubuntu snmpd[4281]: Received TERM or STOP signal...  shutting down...
>   Apr 11 23:09:58 ubuntu snmpd[4401]: iquerySecName has not been configured - internal queries will fail
>   Apr 11 23:09:58 ubuntu snmpd[4401]: /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 77: Error: No address associated with hostname
>   Apr 11 23:09:58 ubuntu snmpd[4401]: /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 91: Error: bad SUBTREE object id
>   Apr 11 23:09:58 ubuntu snmpd[4401]: /etc/snmp/snmp.conf: line 6: Warning: Unknown token: com2sec.
>   Apr 11 23:09:58 ubuntu snmpd[4401]: net-snmp: 2 error(s) in config file(s)
>   Apr 11 23:09:58 ubuntu snmpd[4401]: NET-SNMP version 5.4.3

I double checked what PID the daemon it currently running at and it is indeed 4401.

I did not build SNMP version 5.4.3. I'm confused. It is also telling me there are errors in my configuration too, perhaps this is why I am having such problems at the moment because my configuration file is for that of a later version.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is not related to programming and should be moved to serverfault or superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hazarding a guess: you didn't remove the original package that came
with Ubuntu; you left the locations for the manually compiled version
at /usr/local, which (possibly?) come before the ones that came with
the OS in the PATH; that would explain the correct version on the 
command line.  The startup scripts use the hardcoded PATH to the old
ones?

Edit the init script to point at the new demon :)

Comment: What would you recommend?

Comment: Since my answer was just a guess: can you confirm that my assumptions were correct? If they were, edit the init script to reflect the desired path.

Comment: "...you left the locations for the manually compiled version at /usr/local". Yes I did. "...edit the init script to reflect the desired path" But I left the default /usr/local path when I complied it. What use would editing the init script? Btw, you are talking about `/etc/init.d/snmpd`, yes?

Comment: Actully, looking in the /etc/init.d/snmpd script I can see that the daemon is referenced at `/usr/sbin/snmpd`. Checking this with the `--version` flag does give the old version. Damn.

Comment: So my guesswork and the suggestion to edit the init script are sound.  Sweet.

Comment: Yeah, 'points coming your way. The init script is full of the /usr/sbin directory, I need to put in the /usr/local/sbin. Wouldn't it be easier to just sym link the snmpd executable from /usr/local/sbin/ to /usr/sbin? How would I do that?

Comment: You could do that, just need to kill the existing executables you're about to replace.  Once done it's as easy as "ln -s /usr/local/sbin/snmpd /usr/sbin/snmpd" (and so forth).

Comment: The symlink didn't work. I'm getting it running with starting it directly and not through the init script. Thanks for the help.